# Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table message when using simba jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, google-bigquery

I am using the Simba Jdbc driver version 1.2.2.1004 to sequentially insert 6 rows of data into a BigQuery table. The table only has 3 columns.
After 4 inserts I see:

Caused by: com.simba.googlebigquery.support.exceptions.GeneralException: [Simba]BigQueryJDBCDriver Error executing query job. Message: Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table. For more information, see https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/troubleshooting-errors

I've looked at the quotas on the google side but none of them seems to be reached.
If I throttle the inserts, all the rows get inserted so it's not a day limit, it seems to be the number of inserts per second, but that should be at least 10 according to my quota...

I have also created a test class that insrts the same values using the google api, that works just fine..

Answer (score 4):

You hit this quota, 5 ops / 10s. So, limiting your rate would help.

If possible, try to group smaller updates into big ones to avoid this quota.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables

> Maximum rate of table metadata update operations — 5 operations every 10 seconds per table
>
> The table metadata update limit includes all metadata update operations performed by using the Cloud Console, the classic BigQuery web UI, the bq command-line tool, the client libraries, by calling the tables.insert, tables.patch, or tables.update API methods, or executing ALTER TABLE DDL statements. This limit also applies to job output.

Comment: Hi Yun, 
I've seen this quota but I'm not updating the table metadata, just the data...in all honesty, not really sure what the driver code does, but I cannot see why they would update the table metadata....
The documentation refers to the tables.insert, meaning creating tables, right?

Comment: @mihai I believe load jobs also count, I just run into "Exceeded rate limits: too many partitioned table update operations for this table" and all I am doing is load jobs (I was previously using streaming insertion but I started hitting range limits). So I guess I will have to try a mix between streaming insertion and load jobs with exponential backoff. 

Btw, it seems they have clarified the docs: ```If you exceed this limit, you get an error message like Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table.```